# Error: ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list while removing folders from dir list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am getting above error when I am trying to remove .zip files from my directory list

```
>>> from os import listdir
>>> from os.path import isfile,join
>>> dr = listdir(r"C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\ronit")
>>> dr
```

output:

```
['7101', '7101.zip', '7102', '7102.zip', '7103', '7103.zip']
```

Now for removing .zip files I wrote following code:

```
>>> dr.remove("*.zip")
```

output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#18>", line 1, in <module>
dr.remove("*.zip")
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
```

where am I going wrong?

Comment: Do you want to remove it from your directory? Or the variable?

Comment: Isn't it obvious from the error? `"*.zip"` is not in your list...

Comment: Can anyone tell my why this actually does nothing? thanks `names = [x for x in names if x is not None or '00000']` Id frankly like to clean this up the whole thing is `names= list(df_ora['CODE'].unique())
names.append("00000")
names = [x for x in names if x != None]
names = [x for x in names if x != '00000']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use wildcards when removing from a `list`, you have to iterate through it if you want to do away with partial matches, e.g.:

```
filtered_list = [file_name for file_name in dr if file_name[-4:] != ".zip"]
# ['7101', '7102', '7103']
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, any reason for not using `endswith`?

Comment: I think it would be more robust if you used `.endswith()` instead of relying on slice notation.

Comment: @Wondercricket - performance... `str.endswith()` does exactly the same, just after going through a couple of hoops. You get 10-20% speed increase in dependence of Python version and it's not as if it's cryptic or unreadable to be considered 'non-Pythonic'.

Comment: @zwer `str.endswith` seems easier to extend (with a tuple) for additional file extensions and some may not be 4 characters long (including the period)

Comment: Let me be clear, I'm not denying the benefits of `str.endswith()` - it does the dirty work of figuring out the length of a passed string and creates a slice based on that which in certain situations can be faster than doing your own slicing (as it happens on the C side in CPython)... I'm denying it's 'usefulness' (or rather advocate for better performant versions) in strict cases like this one where we upfront know what we're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
from os import listdir
from os.path import join

dir = 'C:\\Users\\lenovo\\Desktop\\ronit'
dr=os.listdir(dir)

for f in dr:
    if item.endswith(".zip"):
        os.remove(join(dir, f))
```

Comment: Seeing how the other answer was accepted, it can be assumed that the OP was not asking for removing the file from the directory